# How to use the max(date) in where MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am having a problem using the `max(date)` in my where clause.

i have duplicated data in my tables, and some data don't have any duplicated value, i need to select the latest data from each duplicated value, whenever i use the max(date) in my where clause i am having an error of "invalid function"

`sample table`

```
id   user_id  name        date
1       1      Bob        2019-11-12 18:00:00
2       1      Alice      2019-11-12 16:15:15
3       2      Josh       2019-11-08 16:15:15
4       3      Dina       2019-11-09 16:15:15
5       4      Jena       2019-11-07 16:15:15
```

Here is my sample output:

```
id   user_id  name        date
1       1      Bob        2019-11-12 18:00:00
3       2      Josh       2019-11-08 16:15:15
4       3      Dina       2019-11-09 16:15:15
5       4      Jena       2019-11-07 16:15:15
```

so it will only have 4 output because the user_id `1` has a duplicated value i just need to select the latest date from it.

here is my query

```
SELECT name
FROM sample
GROUP BY user_id
WHERE date = max(date);
```

even if i am using group by and order by, i am still not getting the latest date from each duplicated value.

but i am having an error of `invalid function`
any help would be really appreciated. advance thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
select e.name from
sample e 
inner join
    (select user_id, max(date) as dt from sample
    group by user_id) as t1 on t1.user_id = e.user_id and t1.dt = e.date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT name
FROM sample
GROUP BY user_id
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM sample)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql 8.0 or newer, you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select * from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date desc) rn from sample
) a where rn = 1;
```

for older versions, you have to do `JOIN`:

```
select s1.* from sample s1
join (
    select user_id, max(date) date from sample group by date
) s2 on s1.user_id = s2.user_id and s1.date = s2.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's ok

```
SELECT a.`name` FROM (
SELECT *
FROM sample
ORDER BY `date` DESC
) AS a 
GROUP BY a.`name`
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it. What have you changed and why?